# Doubt about $\partial\bar{\partial}$-lemma

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, hodge-theory

Here is a version of $\partial\bar{\partial}$-lemma from Voisin's book.

[image: Voisin]

I'm confused. If we take $f$ to be any smooth function on $X$ and set $\omega=df$, doesn't the proposition imply that $\omega$ has to be zero? Am I missing something?

Comment: $df$ isn't both $\partial$ and $\bar{\partial}$ closed, isn't it?

Comment: @Didier: I think he means that if $\omega=df$ is both $\partial$- and $\bar\partial$-closed, which is the case if $\partial\bar\partial f=0$, then $\omega$ must be zero. I, too, interpreted the statement like that. However, if $X$ is the complex plane, then $\omega=dz$ satisfy all criteria, but is not zero. Perhaps $X$ has to be compact?

Comment: @Didier That's the condition I overlooked! Somehow I took for granted that "$\partial$ and $\bar{\partial}$-closed" is the same as $d$-closed. This is not true when the form has mixed type.

Comment: @EinarRødland Yes, $X$ has to be compact. The condition $\partial\bar{\partial}f=0$ would imply that $\partial f$ is a holomorphic 1-form, but since $X$ is compact Kahler, holomorphic 1-form $\partial f$ is harmonic, which implies that $\partial f=0$, similarly $\bar{\partial}f=0$. I was puzzled on something more elementary.